# How to remove apostrobe in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bash

my mysqli insert statement is not working, as I am trying to inset the whois information for a domain into a mysql database, however for certain domain names such as .co.uk/.com they have a    "     '    " apostrobe in them, which breaks the mysql statement.

I have tried running the variable through mysql_real_escape_string , str_replace and i even have a tr -d \'\'\ on the end of the command (Which works on the linux command line, but not in the script).

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? it is specifically the $whois1 and $whois variable causing the issue. I dont know why getting rid of an apostrobe is so hard.

This is the str_replace i tried (which didnt work)

```
$whois1 = str_replace("'"," ",$whois1);
```

see the below current code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>CWCS Domain Checker Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.php">
  <img src="cwcs-logo.png">
  </a>
</div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="buttonholder">
  <form  action="domainchecker.php" method="post">
    <label for="domain"> <input class="submit" type="text" name="domain" /> </label>
    <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Query" />
  </form>
  <a href="history.php" type="button" class="submitbutton">Search History</a>
</div>
  <?php
  #functions for grabbing data
  $domain = $_POST['domain'];
      function getWhois($domain)
      {
        $whoisOutput = shell_exec("whois $domain | tr -d '\'\' ");
        return $whoisOutput;

      }

      function getSSL($domain)
      {
        $sslOutput = shell_exec("curl --insecure -v https://$domain 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'");
        return $sslOutput;
      }

      function getDNSA($domain)
      {
        $dnsOutputA = shell_exec("dig $domain A | grep A | grep -v ns | grep $domain");
        return $dnsOutputA;
      }

      function getDNSMX($domain)
      {
        $dnsOutputMX = shell_exec("dig $domain MX | grep MX | grep -v ns| grep $domain");
        return $dnsOutputMX;
      }

      function getDNSTXT($domain)
      {
        $dnsOutputTXT= shell_exec("dig $domain TXT | grep TXT | grep -v ns | grep $domain");
        return $dnsOutputTXT;
      }

      function getDNSNS($domain)
      {
        $dnsOutputNS = shell_exec("dig $domain NS | grep NS | grep -v A |  grep $domain");
        return $dnsOutputNS;
      }

      function getBlacklist($domain)
      {
        $ip = gethostbyname("$domain")
        $blackListOutput = shell_exec("curl -I -X GET api.moocher.io/badip/$ip");

        return $blackListOutput;
      }

      function getPing($domain)
      {
        $pingOutput = shell_exec("ping -c 3 $domain");
        return $pingOutput;
      }
      function getTracert($domain)
      {
        $tracertOutput = shell_exec("traceroute $domain");
        return $tracertOutput;
      }
      function getNMAP($domain)
      {
        $nmapOutput = shell_exec("nmap $domain");
        return $nmapOutput;
      }
  ?>
  <?php
  #grabs all the information needed for adding to database/displaying.
  $domainname1 = $domain;
  $date1 = date("Y/m/d");
  $whois1 = getWhois($domain);
  $dnsa1 = getDNSA($domain);
  $dnsmx1 = getDNSMX($domain);
  $dnstxt1 = getDNSTXT($domain);
  $dnsns1 = getDNSNS($domain);
  $blacklist1 = getBlacklist($domain);
  $ping1 = getPing($domain);
  $tracert1 = getTracert($domain);
  $nmap1 = getNMAP($domain);
  $sslinfo1 = getSSL($domain);

 ?>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ><h3>DNS Result</h3>
        <pre>
          <?php
          echo $dnsa1;
          echo $dnsmx1;
          echo $dnstxt1;
          echo $dnsns1;
          ?>
        </pre>
      </td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
      <td ><h3>WHOIS Result</h3>
        <pre>
          <?php
                echo $whois1;
          ?>
        </pre>
      </td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
    <td><h3>SSL Result</h3>
      <pre>
        <?php
        echo $sslinfo1;
        ?>
      </pre>
    </td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
      <td><h3>Blacklist Result</h3>
        <pre>
          <?php
            echo $blacklist1;
          ?>
        </pre>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><h3>NMAP Result</h3>
        <pre>
          <?php
            echo $nmap1;
          ?>
        </pre>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><h3>PING/MTR Result</h3>
        <pre>
          <?php
           echo $ping1;
           echo $tracert1;
          ?>
        </pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- MYSQL STORE HISTORY -->
  <?php
  #creates a new mysql connection
  $servername = "localhost";
  $dbname = "domainhistory";


  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if (!$conn)
  {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $domainname = mysqli_real_escape_string($domainame1);
  $date= mysqli_real_escape_string($date1);
  $whois = mysqli_real_escape_string($whois1);
  $dnsa =mysqli_real_escape_string($dnsa1);
  $dnsmx = mysqli_real_escape_string($dnsmx1);
  $dnstext = mysqli_real_escape_string($dnstext1);
  $dnsns = mysqli_real_escape_string($dnsns1);
  $blacklist = mysqli_real_escape_string($blacklist1);
  $ping = mysqli_real_escape_string($ping1);
  $tracert = mysqli_real_escape_string($tracert1);
  $nmap = mysqli_real_escape_string($nmap1);
  $sslinfo = mysqli_real_escape_string($sslinfo1);
  #inserts all the data into the table




  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `history` (`domain`, `date`, `whois`, `dnsa`, `dnsmx`, `dnstxt`, `dnsns`, `blacklist`, `ping`, `tracert`, `nmap`, `sslinfo`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($domain1, $date1, $whois1, $dnsa1, $dnsmx1, $dnstext1, $dnsns1, $blacklist1, $ping1, $tracert1, $nmap1, $sslinfo1);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record create sucessfully";
                        }


  #says if connection/record was sucessful
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
  {
      echo "New record create sucessfully";
  } else
  {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

#closes the mysql connection
  mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>


</html>
```

Comment: 1) You're mixing APIs. mysql_ is not mysqli_, and they don't work together at all. 2) real_escape_string is not secure.  Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). This will fix/bypass your quoting issue, especially since you're not concatenating correctly anyway.

Comment: Please don't post code with your Credentials hardcoded inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use bound parameters, this will take care of sanitising input for you meaning you no longer need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the parameters.

```
...

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `history` (`domain`, `date`, `whois`, `dnsa`, `dnsmx`, `dnstxt`, `dnsns`, `blacklist`, `ping`, `tracert`, `nmap`, `sslinfo`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss', $domainname1, $date1, $whois1, $dnsa1, $dnsmx1, $dnstxt1, $dnsns1, $blacklist1, $ping1, $tracert1, $nmap1, $sslinfo1);

if ($result = $stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record create sucessfully";

...
```

Here is the full file updated and verified working, you'll need to put in username and password of course

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
<meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
<title>CWCS Domain Checker Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <a href="index.php">
<img src="cwcs-logo.png">
</a>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="buttonholder">
<form  action="domainchecker.php" method="post">
  <label for="domain"> <input class="submit" type="text" name="domain" /> </label>
  <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Query" />
</form>
<a href="history.php" type="button" class="submitbutton">Search History</a>
</div>
<?php
#functions for grabbing data
$domain = $_POST['domain'];
    function getWhois($domain)
    {
      $whoisOutput = shell_exec("whois $domain | tr -d '\'\' ");
      return $whoisOutput;

    }

    function getSSL($domain)
    {
      $sslOutput = shell_exec("curl --insecure -v https://$domain 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'");
      return $sslOutput;
    }

    function getDNSA($domain)
    {
      $dnsOutputA = shell_exec("dig $domain A | grep A | grep -v ns | grep $domain");
      return $dnsOutputA;
    }

    function getDNSMX($domain)
    {
      $dnsOutputMX = shell_exec("dig $domain MX | grep MX | grep -v ns| grep $domain");
      return $dnsOutputMX;
    }

    function getDNSTXT($domain)
    {
      $dnsOutputTXT= shell_exec("dig $domain TXT | grep TXT | grep -v ns | grep $domain");
      return $dnsOutputTXT;
    }

    function getDNSNS($domain)
    {
      $dnsOutputNS = shell_exec("dig $domain NS | grep NS | grep -v A |  grep $domain");
      return $dnsOutputNS;
    }

    function getBlacklist($domain)
    {
      $ip = gethostbyname("$domain");
      $blackListOutput = shell_exec("curl -I -X GET api.moocher.io/badip/$ip");

      return $blackListOutput;
    }

    function getPing($domain)
    {
      $pingOutput = shell_exec("ping -c 3 $domain");
      return $pingOutput;
    }
    function getTracert($domain)
    {
      $tracertOutput = shell_exec("traceroute $domain");
      return $tracertOutput;
    }
    function getNMAP($domain)
    {
      $nmapOutput = 'test';//shell_exec("nmap $domain");
      return $nmapOutput;
    }
?>
<?php
#grabs all the information needed for adding to database/displaying.
$domainname1 = $domain;
$date1 = date("Y/m/d");
$whois1 = getWhois($domain);
$dnsa1 = getDNSA($domain);
$dnsmx1 = getDNSMX($domain);
$dnstxt1 = getDNSTXT($domain);
$dnsns1 = getDNSNS($domain);
$blacklist1 = getBlacklist($domain);
$ping1 = getPing($domain);
$tracert1 = getTracert($domain);
$nmap1 = getNMAP($domain);
$sslinfo1 = getSSL($domain);

?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td ><h3>DNS Result</h3>
      <pre>
        <?php
        echo $dnsa1;
        echo $dnsmx1;
        echo $dnstxt1;
        echo $dnsns1;
        ?>
      </pre>
    </td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td ><h3>WHOIS Result</h3>
      <pre>
        <?php
              echo $whois1;
        ?>
      </pre>
    </td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
  <td><h3>SSL Result</h3>
    <pre>
      <?php
      echo $sslinfo1;
      ?>
    </pre>
  </td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><h3>Blacklist Result</h3>
      <pre>
        <?php
          echo $blacklist1;
        ?>
      </pre>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><h3>NMAP Result</h3>
      <pre>
        <?php
          echo $nmap1;
        ?>
      </pre>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><h3>PING/MTR Result</h3>
      <pre>
        <?php
         echo $ping1;
         echo $tracert1;
        ?>
      </pre>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- MYSQL STORE HISTORY -->
<?php
#creates a new mysql connection
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "domainhistory";
$username = "";
$password = "";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

#inserts all the data into the table




$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `history` (`domain`, `date`, `whois`, `dnsa`, `dnsmx`, `dnstxt`, `dnsns`, `blacklist`, `ping`, `tracert`, `nmap`, `sslinfo`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss', $domainname1, $date1, $whois1, $dnsa1, $dnsmx1, $dnstxt1, $dnsns1, $blacklist1, $ping1, $tracert1, $nmap1, $sslinfo1);

if ($result = $stmt->execute()) {
  echo "New record create sucessfully";
}

#closes the mysql connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>


</html>
```

Comment: I tried this, still same error. However again works fine on .org domain names ect as they do not have the " ' " in registrants. I have updated the code to show what I used.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's address: 1 Bowden Drive Beeston Nottingham Not' at line 2.   It refers to when you do a " whois domain"  inside of the text returned it has  "Registrant's address" I believe it is the "  '  " in registrants that is breaking the statement.  However everything i try, i just cant get rid of that bloody apostrobe.

Comment: Can you add the values for the variables to your original post, bound parameters shouldn't be concerned with quotes.

Comment: The values will change depending on which ever domain name you search.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to recreate the query.

Comment: What values do you need?  for example if you do a whois facebook.com the error changes to - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is currently set t' at line 2

Comment: I've updated the answer, this works fine for me checking google.co.uk and facebook.com. I've also provided the entire working script.

Comment: Strange, I copied and pasted your whole script (put my own UN/Password in) and i still get  -   Connection #0 to host google.co.uk left intact ' )
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's address: 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View CA ' at line 2

Comment: I've checked my DB and there's no apostrophe around the address, before 's address' is 'Registrants address:'. Every column in my table was TEXT and utf8_unicode_ci, I'm running on PHP 5.6. I'm not sure what else to tell you but it works fine for me.

Comment: My collums are LONGTEXT i am not sure how to set view the uft8_unicode bit, I created it using - CREATE TABLE history (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, domain VARCHAR(50), date VARCHAR(30), whois LONGTEXT, dnsa LONGTEXT, dnsmx LONGTEXT, dnstxt LONGTEXT, dnsns LONGTEXT, blacklist LONGTEXT, ping LONGTEXT, tracert LONGTEXT, nmap LONGTEXT, sslinfo LONGTEXT); I am running PHP 7

Comment: Does it work if you set the variables manually? Can you run the insert directly on the MySQL prompt without error?

Comment: No, if i run an insert command on the commandline and it has a "  '   " in it it just carries on as if you had not used a " ; " to close the statement, so i get the  > prompt. ><  How can an apostrophe cause so much trouble.

Comment: the bit that confuses me the most is on linux command line the tr -d \'\'\ remove the apostrophe but doesn't seem to work with here. Also mysql escape doesnt work, neither does using a prepared statement....

Comment: It’s not an apostrophe, I think you’re mixing up the error message as it enclosed the error in apostrophes. My reply a couple or replies ago showed it is stopping after “Registrants Address:” with no apostrophe

Comment: Fixed it by following the below - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes in the insert statement are wrong. It needs single quotes.
More correct:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `history` (`domain`,`date`,`whois`,`dnsa`,`dnsmx`,`dnstxt`,`dnsns`,`blacklist`,`ping`,`tracert`,`nmap`, `sslinfo`)
  VALUES ('$domain', '$date', '$whois', '$dnsa', '$dnsmx', '$dnstxt', '$dnsns', '$blacklist', '$ping', '$tracert', '$nmap', '$sslinfo' )";
```

Even more correct is to use **prepared statements** with placeholders in the SQL. (As Aynber said).

Answer (score 0):

you have escape single quotes in sql.

Ex:

I''m -> will be stored in db as I'm

You need to escape the literals in string values. ( you can see double single quotes here - NOT DOUBLE QUOTES).

```
$whois1 = str_replace("'","''",$whois1);
```

I can see, there is a binding issue. You have escaped:

```
 $domainname = mysqli_real_escape_string($domainame1);
```

**but inserted with $domainame1 instead $domainame;**

Comment: He is already using `mysqli_real_escape_string` and it isn't mandatory to escape the quotes. if he wants the quotes replaced, he should do it before using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Also you need to work on your answers and spend a little more time on them. For example you could explain why you replace two quotes with space, not one quote.

Comment: Thanks @Adder. Sorry, its a typo. BTW, he used "mysqli_real_escape_string" but binded wrong parameters. as you can see,  $domainname = mysqli_real_escape_string($domainame1); But inserted with $domainname1. Which is invalid.

Comment: That should be correct,   The new variable is $domainname and the old variable was $domainname1  (which is at the top of the script)  Unless I am miss understand how it works.

Comment: @VIRA I see what you mean. But actually it is correct because the entire `mysqli_real_escape_string` block can be removed because the prepared statement does the escaping.